# Google Analytic's Tag Manager Video Trigger

Tags: community, google-analytics, video, tag-manager

Has anyone successfully used GA's Tag Manager's Video trigger options to determine when a Youtube video on a Community page is played?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to track Google Analytics when a user presses play on a Youtube video on a Community page.  It isn't the prettiest code, but it is a works & is a start.  Not sure why my code isn't pasting as code.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="DisplayTopFiveNewestMembersForPortal" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="False" applyHtmlTag="False">
```

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-123274077-1', 'auto');
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
 var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'Youtube Video Test2', 'test');        
    alert("Video Playing");
    }
  }